# javascript loop behaving erratically while using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
var last=0;
var sub=document.getElementById("sub");
var msg=document.getElementById('msg');
var msg_bx=document.getElementById("msg_bx");
    var re=new XMLHttpRequest();
re.open("GET","handler.php?mode=begin",true);
re.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(re.status==200 && re.readyState==4){
        //console.log(re.responseText);
        var data=JSON.parse(re.responseText);
        if(data.err_msg){
            alert(data.err_msg);
        }
        else {
            for(var o in data){
                struct(data[o]);
            }
        }
    }
}
re.send(null);
function struct(data){
            s=data.sender;
            m=data.msg;
            t=data.time;
            i=data.id;
            var bx=document.createElement("div");
            bx.className="msg";
            msg_bx.appendChild(bx);
            var sen=document.createElement("div");
            bx.appendChild(sen);
            sen.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Sent by:"+s));
            var msg=document.createElement("div");
            bx.appendChild(msg);
            msg.appendChild(document.createTextNode(m));
            if(i>=last){
                last=i;
            }
            console.log(i+"   "+last);
}
});
```

the console data coming as::

```
   2   2 chat.js:64
    3   3 chat.js:64
    4   4 chat.js:64
    5   5 chat.js:64
    6   6 chat.js:64
    7   7 chat.js:64
    8   8 chat.js:64
    9   9 chat.js:64
    10   9 chat.js:64
    11   9 chat.js:64

{"count1":{
                "id":"2",
                "sender":"1",
                "msg":"bbfkjvndk?",
                "time":"1386494886"
            },"count2":{
                "id":"3",
                "sender":"1",
                "msg":"bubjhadljlkvdjovjj;ojkd?",
                "time":"1386494931"
            },"count3":{
                "id":"4",
                "sender":"1",
                "msg":"vidhu?",
                "time":"1386494982"
            },"count4":{
                "id":"5",
                "sender":"1",
                "msg":"bvfiuefhilnfdigvfuodahfasviubjcabsyvgUVHJVKJFHV9dhf79gvhkebfvkjhdovi;h7zv9jvhdsbviy7dg89hvdsbyuavgd?",
                "time":"1386495013"
            },"count5":{
                "id":"6",
                "sender":"1",
                "msg":"what the hel??",
                "time":"1386495367"
            },"count6":{
                "id":"7",
                "sender":"1",
                "msg":"?",
                "time":"1386497097"
            },"count7":{
                "id":"8",
                "sender":"1",
                "msg":"?",
                "time":"1386497097"
            },"count8":{
                "id":"9",
                "sender":"1",
                "msg":"what do u want with me??",
                "time":"1386506545"
            },"count9":{
                "id":"10",
                "sender":"1",
                "msg":"so g otbjobjsd?",
                "time":"1386506554"
            },"count10":{
                "id":"11",
                "sender":"1",
                "msg":"what the hell??",
                "time":"1386507581"
            }} chat.php:13
```

the loop stops incrementing last after 9.
the struct function is being used to make a basic structure and is called when data comes as json. 
last increments with i value till it reaches 9 and then becomes due to some reason constant even when i is increasing

Comment: Why so much code and a incomprehensible question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `"10" >= "9"` is `false` in Javascript.

I suspect that `data.id` is a string. This makes `i` and `last` strings too and during the comparison `i >= last`, they are compared as strings.

You could convert it to a number before comparing them: `i = +data.id;` and then `10 >= 9` will be `true`.